# Compare String with values to String with Placeholders to find values out of it

Tags: java

I have template like below

```
Hello {user}, your  request id is {id}, -------1
```

And I have text with values filled in it like

```
Hello ABC , your  request id is 1234.  --------2
```

Now Input to my program is 2 and I want to retrieve values like

```
 {user} = ABC
 {id}   = 1234
```

Can you please suggest me any solution for the above problem. Thanks in advance.

I want to retrieve values where I have placeholders in template. The input is string with values and I have to match Template with that string to retrieve values of place holder from template in that string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the template to do the parsing, you could do the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String template = "Hello {user}, your  request id is {id}.";
    String withValues = "Hello ABC , your  request id is 1234.";

    String patternFromTemplate = template.replaceAll("\\.", "\\\\."); // escape "." 
    patternFromTemplate = patternFromTemplate.replace("{user}", "(.*)"); // capturing group 1
    patternFromTemplate = patternFromTemplate.replace("{id}", "(.*)"); // capturing group 2

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patternFromTemplate);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(withValues);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("{user} = "+m.group(1));
        System.out.println("{id}   = "+m.group(2));
    } 
}
```

But be careful with characters (like `.`) in your template that have a special meaning when the string is used as a regex. And note that this will break if your pattern changes significantly (for example, if `id` comes first or `id` or `user` don't appear in the template at all).

What it does:

- Escape all `.` characters in the template, so they don't mess up the regex
- Replace `{user}` in the template with `(.*)` (capturing group 1)
- Replace `{id}` in the template with `(.*)` (capturing group 2)
- Apply the regex to your string with values
- Extract the matches (if the regex matches)

Basically the same that @zx81 suggested, the only difference is that here the regex is created dynamically, based on the template.

Comment: Thanks mth can you please explain a bit. It works great.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to capture the strings to Groups 1 and 2, then retrieve:

```
Hello ([^,]+), your request id is ([^.]+)
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN1dX1).

Your spacings were inconsistent so I tidied them up, also using the period as a delimiter for the `id` field, but it can all be tweaked.

**Sample Code**

```
String userName = null;
String userID = null;
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("Hello ([^,]+), your request id is ([^.]+)");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    userName = regexMatcher.group(1);
    userID = regexMatcher.group(2);
    }
```

**Explanation**

- `Hello` matches `Hello` and one space
- The parentheses in `([^,]+)` capture  to Group 1 any chars that are not commas
- `, your request id is` match literal character
- `([^.]+)`  capture  to Group 1 any chars that are not period.

This assumes that there will be a period after your ID, as in `Hello ABC, your request id is 1234.` If not, we change the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I want place holders there not regex. Because these place holders will be put by user which does not know anything about regex.

Comment: Not sure I understand. :) You tagged your question `regex` and said ` I am weak in regex`. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I tried this using regex and it works for me. But I was searching for template regex where in I would match Template with actual string which will give me result like I have mentioned above.

Comment: Okay, I had misunderstood. Please have a look at the solution by @mth :)